# replace text in Richtext box VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, richtextbox

im solving one problem in text in Rich text box (VB.net). It does not work.

Do you know where i have problem?

```
Dim number_lines As Integer
number_lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count
Dim counting As Integer
counting = 0
For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    counting = counting + 1

    If ((number_lines - 1) = counting) Or (number_lines = counting) Then

    Else
        If line.Contains("M30") Then
           Me.RichTextBox1.Lines(counting).Replace("M30", "")
        End If

        If line.Contains("M406") Then
            Me.RichTextBox1.Lines(counting).Replace("M406", "M405")
            'line.Replace("M406", "M405")
        End If
    End If
Next line
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in NET. You are taking the string, replacing the text but the original string is unchanged

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will do this another way.